# Syntax error in SQL RDS server for create table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement to update the created date and updated date column in MS SQL server. I'm using below query to do the same. But while executing the query I'm getting a syntax error saying **"Syntax error near 'ON'"**.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
  dt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Can someone please point me where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what you are trying to do with this `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: For starters you are using the timestamp datatype. This has nothing to do with time of day. You should instead use datetime. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql And no idea what that "ON UPDATE" bit is trying to do.

Comment: Can you find any `ON` in your statement?

Comment: You need to handle the update in a trigger

Comment: @TheGameiswar on update of the existing row, update the time stamp.

Comment: @scsimon i don't want to use trigger.

Comment: If you want to update the dt column when an update happens a trigger is the only way, or have that column updated in your update procedure.

Comment: Well...that link is for MySql, you have this tagged as sql server. They are not the same thing.

Comment: i think  you are looking for computed column,some thing like `dt as ts`

Comment: @TheGameiswar Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: You can ignore,the one i mentioned is for sqlserver\

Comment: @SeanLange I'm looking for similar syntax in ms Sql

Comment: please remove those incompatible tags

Comment: To accomplish this in sql server you have to use the datetime datatype, then you need to create an update trigger on the table. The trigger is the mechanism to handle the update event in sql server.

Comment: Try this
CREATE TABLE TestTS
(
    ts DATETIME DEFAULT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ,
 dt DATETIME DEFAULT(GETDATE())
)

Answer (score 0):

Either use a `PERSISTED COMPUTED COLUMN` to handle the DateTime refresh.
Or use an `UPDATE TRIGGER`.

I suggest the use of a Trigger because COMPUTED COLUMN may be refreshed even if the ROW is not Updated.